# Specification of ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME

Tags: ros, ros-hostname, network, ros-master-uri, ros-ip

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I would like to us ros for multiple robot instances, but have some doubts about the network setup.
The idea is to have two robots that are communicating in a network.
Each of them have seperate control packages that should run local on the robots.
However they should be able to send information in the form of the rostopics topic1 and topic2.
Accordingly we want to create following setup:

```
robot1 192.168.1.1
    locally running ros-package: control1 
         subscribing topic2
         publishing  topic1                 

robot2 192.168.1.2
    locally running ros-package: control2
         subscribing topic1
         publishing  topic2
```

As we need one ros-master to control the communication, we choose 192.168.1.1 as master.
Therefore we execute locally on robot 1:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.1:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.1
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.1   
roscore
```

In order to connect to the ROS-master, we execute locally on robot2:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.1.1.1:11311            
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.2                               
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.2
```

Afterwards we execute the controllers locally.
My question is:

> 1. Does the shown workflow lead to the desired behavior (controllers running
>    locally).
> 2. Why are the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME defined seperately
> 3. Why do we need to specify ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME

Thanks a lot for unravel my confusion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272065/specification-of-ros_master_uri-and-ros_hostname/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
I hate to just point to documentation, but just to make sure you've seen it: [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and [wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines).
That should clear up some of your questions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
Also: don't use `ROS_HOSTNAME` if you're not setting a hostname. Use `ROS_IP` for that. And don't use them both. If you only have IP addressing, use `ROS_IP`. If you have a working DNS, use `ROS_HOSTNAME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> **Question 1** Does the shown workflow lead to the desired behavior (controllers running locally).

Yes, just remove the `export ROS_HOSTNAME ..` commands on both machines. Read the answer to question 3 to know why.

> **Question 2** Why are the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME defined seperately

When you run ROS nodes on multiple machines, you need to start ***just 1 master process***. The `ROS_MASTER_URI` will have the address of the machine on which you will run the master process (which is done by `roscore` or `roslaunch..` commands). **So this value should be the same on all machines**. Whereas `ROS_HOSTNAME` or `ROS_IP` will have the values of the hostname or IP of machine where you will run ROS nodes. **So these variables will have different values on all machines.**

> **Question 3** Why do we need to specify ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME?

If a machine reports a hostname that is not addressable by other machines, then you need to set either the `ROS_IP` or `ROS_HOSTNAME` environment variables. You don't need to specify both `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_IP` together, both are mutually exclusive. Reproducing the text from the docs:

> ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME are optional environment variable that sets the declared network address of a ROS Node or tool. The options are mutually exclusive, if both are set ROS_HOSTNAME will take precedence. Use ROS_IP if you are specifying an IP address, and ROS_HOSTNAME if you are specifying a host name. When a ROS component reports a URI to the master or other components, this value will be used. This setting is only needed in situations where you have multiple addresses for a computer and need to force ROS to a particular one.

Source: [ROS/EnvironmentVariables](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME)

The setup which will work for you:

On robot 1

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.1:11311
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.1   
roscore
```

On robot 1 (new tab)

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.1:11311
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.1   
rosrun control1 <node_name>
```

On robot 2:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.1.1.1:11311            
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.2
rosrun control2 <node_name>
```

---

Originally posted by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) with karma: 512 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13